# Using a multi-character field separator in awk on Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris

I wish to use a string (BIRCH) as a field delimiter in `awk` to print second field. I am trying the following command:

```
cat tmp.log|awk -FBirch '{ print $2}'
```

Below output is getting printed:

> irch2014/06/23,04:36:45,3,1401503,xml-harlan,P12345-1,temp,0a653356353635635,temp,L,Success

Desired output:

> 2014/06/23,04:36:45,3,1401503,xml-harlan,P12345-1,temp,0a653356353635635,temp,L,Success

Contents of **tmp.log** file.

```
-bash-3.2# cat tmp.log  
Dec 05 13:49:23 [x.x.x.x.180.100] business-log-dev/int [TEST][0x80000001][business-log][info] mpgw(Test): trans(8497187)[request][10.x.x.x]:
Birch2014/06/23,04:36:45,3,1401503,xml-harlan,P12345-1,temp,0a653356353635635,temp,L,Success
```

Am I doing something wrong?

- OS: Solaris10
- Shell: Bash

Tried below command suggested in one of the ansers below. I am getting the desired output, but with an extra empty line at the top. How can this be eliminated from the output?

`-bash-3.2# /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -FBirch '{print $2}' tmp.log`

`2014/06/23,04:36:45,3,1401503,xml-harlan,P12345-1,temp,0a653356353635635,temp,L,Success`

Comment: If you have just two fields, how about `sed 's/.*Birch//' file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, I suggested putting quotes around "Birch" (`-F'Birch'`) but actually, I don't think that should make any difference.

I'm not at all experienced working with Solaris but you may want to also try using `nawk` ("new awk") instead of `awk`.

```
nawk -FBirch '{print $2}' file
```

If this works, you may want to consider creating an alias so that you always use the newer version of awk with more features.

You may also want to try using the version of awk in the `/usr/xpg4/bin` directory, which is a POSIX compliant implementation so should support multi-character `FS`:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -FBirch '{print $2}' file
```

If you only want to print lines which have more than one field, you can add a condition:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -FBirch 'NF>1{print $2}' file
```

This only prints the second field when there is more than one field.

Comment: Solaris awk only takes a single character as FS

Comment: @Ed yeah, to be honest I was only guessing with the BEGIN block. I have edited it out of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of the default awk on solaris `usr/bin/awk`

```
-Fc            Uses the character c as the  field  separator
               (FS)  character.   See  the  discussion of FS
               below.
```

As you can see solaris awk only takes a single character as a Field separator

Also in the man page is split

```
split(s, a, fs)

     Split the string s into array elements a[1],  a[2],  ...
     a[n],  and  returns  n.  The separation is done with the
     regular expression fs or with the field separator FS  if
     fs is not given.
```

As you can see here it takes a regular expression as a separator so we can use.

```
awk 'split($0,a,"Birch"){print a[2]}' file
```

To print the second field split by `Birch`

Comment: I am getting below error when I use this command.

`awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: To be clear, there is no such thing as `Solaris awk`. Solaris is a platform provided by Sun which comes with 3 different versions of awk - /usr/bin/awk (aka `oawk` or "old, broken awk"), nawk ("new awk"), and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. Any time you get the error message `awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1` it means you are using old, broken awk. Do not do that, use one of the others.

Comment: @EdMorton i meant the default on solaris(which is /usr/bin/awk) , probably could have been clearer though